# sql server - How to properly insert/update data with central european characters

Tags: sql-server

I have a proprietary software that communicates with sql server database for storing data and trying to insert/update records behind the scenes.

Running `Select @@version` on server returns

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB4019093) - 12.0.5207.0 (X64) 
Jul  3 2017 02:25:44 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
```

server collation is `Slovenian_CI_AS`, but all string columns in tables are declared with:

```
DATA_TYPE: nvarchar
CHARACTER_SET_NAME: UNICODE
COLLATION_NAME: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Now if I try updating a field, for example:

```
UPDATE CategoryText SET Title = 'č' WHERE Category_Id = 1 AND LanguageId = 1060"
```

The software displays Ä as a title.

Of course, I get the right result (letter č) if i run the following query from the console

```
select Title from CategoryText where Category_Id = 1 AND LanguageId = 1060
```

But I would like to insert the text the way that will be displayed properly in the software.

Doing this from ubuntu with en_US.UTF-8 local settings, tried also from windows without luck. 
I can change my local settings, I can change the collation of the string I'm importing. 
I cannot change the way software is communicating with the server and I do not think I can alter the tables in the database.

Comment: You need to specify your string literal as nvarchar by adding an N. Like this. N'č'

Comment: Don't try to "fix" any collations, settings or locales. They aren't broken. It's the query itself that's broken, and/or the column type. Use NVARCHAR columns and Unicode literals, ie `= N'Δεν Είναι Αγγλικά'` instead of `= 'Δεν Είναι Αγγλικά'. Windows and SQL Server support Unicode natively since day 1, way back when Windows NT and the first version of SQL Server came out.

Comment: An even better solution is to *avoid* string literals altogether, use parameterized queries and pass strings as parameters. You avoid any bugs caused by ASCII literals and improve execution plan reuse

Comment: Thanks. I have actually tried this already, but it didn't work. I see now that it works on my windows machine. Do you have any clue why it doesn't work on ubuntu?

Comment: Parametrized query did the trick. Thank you.